# How to enable wifi direct on a BeagleBone with Arch Linux using a rtl8188cus chip?

Tags: arm, archlinux, wifi-direct, beagleboneblack, wifip2p

I try to implement wifi DIRECT (p2p) on my beaglebone running under a standard arch linux distribution.

my wifi chip is rtl8188cus and it use the rtl8192cu driver

All my drivers are correctly loaded :

```
[root@alarm ~]# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
arc4                    1660  2 
rtl8192cu              88159  0 
rtlwifi                78157  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        60321  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              496147  3 rtlwifi,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              421700  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
rfkill                 18407  1 cfg80211
g_ether                27657  0 
libcomposite           17081  1 g_ether
autofs4                21976  2
```

and I can see that my device allow wifi-Direct connection on that way :

```
[root@alarm ~]# iw phy0 info
Wiphy phy0
    Band 1:
    Capabilities: 0x1862
        HT20/HT40
        Static SM Power Save
        RX HT20 SGI
        RX HT40 SGI
        No RX STBC
        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
        DSSS/CCK HT40
    Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
    Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
    HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7, 32
    Frequencies:
        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
        * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 1.0 Mbps
        * 2.0 Mbps
        * 5.5 Mbps
        * 11.0 Mbps
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
max # scan SSIDs: 4
max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
RTS threshold: 2347
Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
Supported Ciphers:
    * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
    * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
    * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
    * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
software interface modes (can always be added):
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
interface combinations are not supported
Supported commands:
     * new_interface
     * set_interface
     * new_key
     * start_ap
     * new_station
     * new_mpath
     * set_mesh_config
     * set_bss
     * authenticate
     * associate
     * deauthenticate
     * disassociate
     * join_ibss
     * join_mesh
     * set_tx_bitrate_mask
     * frame
     * frame_wait_cancel
     * set_wiphy_netns
     * set_channel
     * set_wds_peer
     * probe_client
     * set_noack_map
     * register_beacons
     * start_p2p_device
     * set_mcast_rate
     * connect
     * disconnect
Supported TX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
Supported RX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * managed: 0x40 0xd0
     * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
HT Capability overrides:
     * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
     * maximum A-MSDU length
     * supported channel width
     * short GI for 40 MHz
     * max A-MPDU length exponent
     * min MPDU start spacing
Device supports TX status socket option.
Device supports HT-IBSS.
Device supports low priority scan.
Device supports scan flush.
Device supports AP scan.
```

But not in that way :

```
[root@alarm ~]# iwpriv 
wlan0     no private ioctls.

lo        no private ioctls.

eth0      no private ioctls.

usb0      no private ioctls.
```

my wpa_supplicant and is client allow me to launch p2p actions :

```
[root@alarm ~]# wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/root/wpa_0_8.conf &
[1] 273
[root@alarm ~]# Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant

[root@alarm ~]# wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.1
Copyright (c) 2004-2014, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode

> p2p_find
FAIL
> help
commands:
  status [verbose] = get current WPA/EAPOL/EAP status
  ifname = get current interface name
  ping = pings wpa_supplicant
  relog = re-open log-file (allow rolling logs)
  note <text> = add a note to wpa_supplicant debug log
  mib = get MIB variables (dot1x, dot11)
  help [command] = show usage help
  interface [ifname] = show interfaces/select interface
  level <debug level> = change debug level
  license = show full wpa_cli license
  quit = exit wpa_cli
  set = set variables (shows list of variables when run without arguments)
  get <name> = get information
  logon = IEEE 802.1X EAPOL state machine logon
  logoff = IEEE 802.1X EAPOL state machine logoff
  pmksa = show PMKSA cache
  reassociate = force reassociation
  preauthenticate <BSSID> = force preauthentication
  identity <network id> <identity> = configure identity for an SSID
  password <network id> <password> = configure password for an SSID
  new_password <network id> <password> = change password for an SSID
  pin <network id> <pin> = configure pin for an SSID
  otp <network id> <password> = configure one-time-password for an SSID
  passphrase <network id> <passphrase> = configure private key passphrase
    for an SSID
  sim <network id> <pin> = report SIM operation result
  bssid <network id> <BSSID> = set preferred BSSID for an SSID
  blacklist <BSSID> = add a BSSID to the blacklist
  blacklist clear = clear the blacklist
  blacklist = display the blacklist
  log_level <level> [<timestamp>] = update the log level/timestamp
  log_level = display the current log level and log options
  list_networks = list configured networks
  select_network <network id> = select a network (disable others)
  enable_network <network id> = enable a network
  disable_network <network id> = disable a network
  add_network = add a network
  remove_network <network id> = remove a network
  set_network <network id> <variable> <value> = set network variables (shows
    list of variables when run without arguments)
  get_network <network id> <variable> = get network variables
  list_creds = list configured credentials
  add_cred = add a credential
  remove_cred <cred id> = remove a credential
  set_cred <cred id> <variable> <value> = set credential variables
  save_config = save the current configuration
  disconnect = disconnect and wait for reassociate/reconnect command before
    connecting
  reconnect = like reassociate, but only takes effect if already disconnected
  scan = request new BSS scan
  scan_results = get latest scan results
  bss <<idx> | <bssid>> = get detailed scan result info
  get_capability <eap/pairwise/group/key_mgmt/proto/auth_alg/channels/freq/modes> = get capabilies
  reconfigure = force wpa_supplicant to re-read its configuration file
  terminate = terminate wpa_supplicant
  interface_add <ifname> <confname> <driver> <ctrl_interface> <driver_param>
    <bridge_name> = adds new interface, all parameters but <ifname>
    are optional
  interface_remove <ifname> = removes the interface
  interface_list = list available interfaces
  ap_scan <value> = set ap_scan parameter
  scan_interval <value> = set scan_interval parameter (in seconds)
  bss_expire_age <value> = set BSS expiration age parameter
  bss_expire_count <value> = set BSS expiration scan count parameter
  bss_flush <value> = set BSS flush age (0 by default)
  stkstart <addr> = request STK negotiation with <addr>
  ft_ds <addr> = request over-the-DS FT with <addr>
  wps_pbc [BSSID] = start Wi-Fi Protected Setup: Push Button Configuration
  wps_pin <BSSID> [PIN] = start WPS PIN method (returns PIN, if not hardcoded)
  wps_check_pin <PIN> = verify PIN checksum
  wps_cancel Cancels the pending WPS operation
  wps_nfc [BSSID] = start Wi-Fi Protected Setup: NFC
  wps_nfc_config_token <WPS|NDEF> = build configuration token
  wps_nfc_token <WPS|NDEF> = create password token
  wps_nfc_tag_read <hexdump of payload> = report read NFC tag with WPS data
  nfc_get_handover_req <NDEF> <WPS> = create NFC handover request
  nfc_get_handover_sel <NDEF> <WPS> = create NFC handover select
  nfc_rx_handover_req <hexdump of payload> = report received NFC handover request
  nfc_rx_handover_sel <hexdump of payload> = report received NFC handover select
  nfc_report_handover <role> <type> <hexdump of req> <hexdump of sel> = report completed NFC handover
  wps_reg <BSSID> <AP PIN> = start WPS Registrar to configure an AP
  wps_ap_pin [params..] = enable/disable AP PIN
  wps_er_start [IP address] = start Wi-Fi Protected Setup External Registrar
  wps_er_stop = stop Wi-Fi Protected Setup External Registrar
  wps_er_pin <UUID> <PIN> = add an Enrollee PIN to External Registrar
  wps_er_pbc <UUID> = accept an Enrollee PBC using External Registrar
  wps_er_learn <UUID> <PIN> = learn AP configuration
  wps_er_set_config <UUID> <network id> = set AP configuration for enrolling
  wps_er_config <UUID> <PIN> <SSID> <auth> <encr> <key> = configure AP
  wps_er_nfc_config_token <WPS/NDEF> <UUID> = build NFC configuration token
  ibss_rsn <addr> = request RSN authentication with <addr> in IBSS
  sta <addr> = get information about an associated station (AP)
  all_sta = get information about all associated stations (AP)
  deauthenticate <addr> = deauthenticate a station
  disassociate <addr> = disassociate a station
  chan_switch <cs_count> <freq> [sec_channel_offset=] [center_freq1=] [center_freq2=] [bandwidth=] [blocktx] [ht|vht] = CSA parameters
  suspend = notification of suspend/hibernate
  resume = notification of resume/thaw
  drop_sa = drop SA without deauth/disassoc (test command)
  roam <addr> = roam to the specified BSS
  p2p_find [timeout] [type=*] = find P2P Devices for up-to timeout seconds
  p2p_stop_find = stop P2P Devices search
  p2p_connect <addr> <"pbc"|PIN> [ht40] = connect to a P2P Device
  p2p_listen [timeout] = listen for P2P Devices for up-to timeout seconds
  p2p_group_remove <ifname> = remove P2P group interface (terminate group if GO)
  p2p_group_add [ht40] = add a new P2P group (local end as GO)
  p2p_prov_disc <addr> <method> = request provisioning discovery
  p2p_get_passphrase = get the passphrase for a group (GO only)
  p2p_serv_disc_req <addr> <TLVs> = schedule service discovery request
  p2p_serv_disc_cancel_req <id> = cancel pending service discovery request
  p2p_serv_disc_resp <freq> <addr> <dialog token> <TLVs> = service discovery response
  p2p_service_update = indicate change in local services
  p2p_serv_disc_external <external> = set external processing of service discovery
  p2p_service_flush = remove all stored service entries
  p2p_service_add <bonjour|upnp> <query|version> <response|service> = add a local service
  p2p_service_del <bonjour|upnp> <query|version> [|service] = remove a local service
  p2p_reject <addr> = reject connection attempts from a specific peer
  p2p_invite <cmd> [peer=addr] = invite peer
  p2p_peers [discovered] = list known (optionally, only fully discovered) P2P peers
  p2p_peer <address> = show information about known P2P peer
  p2p_set <field> <value> = set a P2P parameter
  p2p_flush = flush P2P state
  p2p_cancel = cancel P2P group formation
  p2p_unauthorize <address> = unauthorize a peer
  p2p_presence_req [<duration> <interval>] [<duration> <interval>] = request GO presence
  p2p_ext_listen [<period> <interval>] = set extended listen timing
  p2p_remove_client <address|iface=address> = remove a peer from all groups
  wfd_subelem_set <subelem> [contents] = set Wi-Fi Display subelement
  wfd_subelem_get <subelem> = get Wi-Fi Display subelement
  sta_autoconnect <0/1> = disable/enable automatic reconnection
  tdls_discover <addr> = request TDLS discovery with <addr>
  tdls_setup <addr> = request TDLS setup with <addr>
  tdls_teardown <addr> = tear down TDLS with <addr>
  signal_poll = get signal parameters
  pktcnt_poll = get TX/RX packet counters
  reauthenticate = trigger IEEE 802.1X/EAPOL reauthentication
  autoscan [params] = Set or unset (if none) autoscan parameters
  raw <params..> = Sent unprocessed command
  flush = flush wpa_supplicant state
  radio_work = radio_work <show/add/done>
```

but it just fail.

I try to found a solution on internet, but found nothing that works.. I tried to recompile my drivers, recompile the wireless-tools, tried to recompile wpa_supplicant and hostapd, but nothing works. If someone could help me, or give me more information on what's going wrong  it will be very nice !

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried a sanity test by connecting your BBB to a known, working wireless access point?  Have you tried a second sanity test that confirms that the other host can also connect to a WAP?

Comment: Yes I successfully connecter to an AP, but I didn't try as an AP...
I load other drivers (8012cu ) that I compiled myself. Now I can see private commands with iwpriv, but iw list return nothing.
Wpa_suppliant cannot be launched  and return an error with nl80211 when it try to change the mode : no such device (-9). mac80211 and 8192cu are correctly loaded.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution : my drivers didn't support nl80211 driver ...
the rtl8192cu driver is NOT compatible with wifi p2p. I have to use the 8192cu one from realtek and recompiled it.

more information and sources on my github : https://github.com/jlucidar/ShopBot-API/tree/master/Arch_linux_config/rtl8188CUS-driver-beaglebone